# How to do Dynamic Web Crawling when page_source is changing as scrolling down

Tags: web-scraping, web, web-crawler

I'm trying to Crawling Data from an website.
The problem is that the source code is changing as I scroll down.

For example

At the first time, page source code is like...

```
<div role="presentation" style="transform: translateY(4088px);">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="1" aria-selected="false">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="2" aria-selected="false">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="3" aria-selected="false">
   ...
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="8" aria-selected="false">
```

As I scroll down

```
<div role="presentation" style="transform: translateY(4088px);">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="22" aria-selected="false">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="23" aria-selected="false">
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="24" aria-selected="false">
   ...
   <div role="row" aria-rowindex="29" aria-selected="false">
```

I want to get info from this tag `<div role="row" aria-rowindex="?" aria-selected="false">`

Now, I'm using this code. `elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@aria-rowindex={num+1}]")`

I thought an Idea that just scroll down little by little and get all info, and scorll again...
But I'm wondering is there any better idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue in 2 ways

1. Use selenium automation to scroll and extract respective div tags
2. Identify the XHR request going in the background when you are scrolling using network debug. Take the request and implement the request in the language that you are comfortable

In Selenium with Ruby, you can use the `execute_script` method to run JavaScript code that scrolls the webpage. Here's an example of how you can scroll down using Selenium in Ruby:

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Set up the Selenium WebDriver
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://testwebsite.com")

# Scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500);")

# Wait for a few seconds to see the effect
sleep(rand(3..5))

# Close the browser
driver.quit
```

This example uses the `window.scrollBy` method in JavaScript to scroll down the page by a specified number of pixels (in this case, 500 pixels). You can adjust the values based on your requirements.

If you want to scroll to a specific element on the page, you can use the `scrollIntoView` method. For example:

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Set up the Selenium WebDriver
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://testwebsite.com")

# Find the element you want to scroll to
element = driver.find_element(:id, 'exampleElement')

# Scroll to the element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)

# Wait for a few seconds to see the effect
sleep(rand(3..5))

# Close the browser
driver.quit
```

In this example, replace `'exampleElement'` with the actual ID or other locator of the element you want to scroll to. The `scrollIntoView` method scrolls the element into the visible area of the browser window.